# How to search for a pattern in a file from the end of a directory using grep?

Tags: unix, grep

I need to search for files containing a pattern in a directory (to search from the end of the directory to the start). 
This is the command I use now, 
grep -rl 'pattern'

Is there any command to search for a pattern from the last file of a directory to the first file?

Comment: There is no order to the files in a directory, so how do you define the *"last"* file? And the *"first"*?

Comment: Sorry, I meant after sorting the files in the order of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `grep` to search in some order, you need to pass it a list of file names in the order you want. If you want the files in the current directory in reverse order of name, `ls -r` would do the job. How about something like this?

```
ls -1br | xargs grep 'pattern'
```

Note the `-b`, which is needed to mitigate problems with spaces and metacharacters in file names.

Note also that this won't cope well with sub-directories. But the principle is sound - generate a list of files in the order you want and pass it to `grep` using `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This really saved me a lot of time.